# Multiple Camera Folders in the Gallery

Tags: external-sd, 4.2-jelly-bean, camera, gallery

Ever since I changed the settings in my camera to store the images on my external SD, there have been two folders in my gallery called "camera." One of these is where all of my photos that I take normally with the camera go, and then the other appears to be the one that Android associates with the default camera gallery and only has a few photos in it. The photos that go to the default camera gallery are normally only ones that I take directly from apps such as when I capture a picture and send it all from my text messaging app.

I have tried deleting the default folder to see if it would then associate the other folder as the default camera folder, but that doesn't solve anything. As soon as I take another picture straight from my text messaging app, there are two folders again. Is there a way that I can merge the folders, or change the settings in my camera app to store the pictures on the external SD and still view them as if they were taken by the default camera?

Comment: "photos that I take normally with the camera go" -- Is this using the stock camera, or a 3rd-party camera app?

Comment: Stock camera. The one that comes with the ROM.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue.  It also caused a related problem.  When I tried to browse the Camera folder on my external sd card, it hangs for about 60 seconds.  So I went to Terminal (if your phone doesn't have this app then download the Terminal Emulator) and did the following (case-sensitive):

`cd //storage/extSdCard/DCIM`
  `mv Camera Recent`

I took me a lot of experimentation to discover the problem and to find a simple fix, but this works just fine for me.  I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URSafe Media Redirector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.venator.app.mediaredirector).

> - Get rid of DCIM folder for pictures, videos and much more ...
> - Redirect files to any folder for any application you want.
> - Easy to use !
> - Fast and Lightweight !
>
> Most of Android users, like me, do not like the folder where Pictures and Videos are written by default because they are mixed, so we developed a tool that enable you to redirect each type of file for its correct place, in an automatic way.
>
> For example, you can redirect all 'Image Files' from '/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/' to '/sdcard/MyPictures', and all 'Video Files' to '/sdcard/MyVideos'. Once these redirections were created, you do not need to worry anymore because all Pictures and Videos taken will go to its right place alone and automatically.

Comment: I don't think this will do what I am looking for. I want to store my picture on the external SD, but I also want it to associate that location with the default location for pictures to be stored.